# 3 menu into a single menu in responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Goal:
When it goes to Responsive design, The menu of "Test1"  and "default" should be included in the menu to be expanded.

Problem:
When you go for responsive design I only can see the menu that is "Asdf" only but it does not contain any menulink from Test1 and default.

I tried finding a solution it does go so well.

How to enable to do it in relation to Bootstrap v3

Thank you!

```
jsbin.com/goqimureva/edit?html,output
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "in" class for bootstrap:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left collapse navbar-collapse in"></ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left collapse navbar-collapse in"></ul>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse in"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this in wrong way. There is no need to add extra ul.

```
`http://jsbin.com/suqabisiyo/1/edit?html,output`
```